# Hashing passwords in database

Tags: java, eclipse, hash

I did the login page for my web application in Eclipse Java using Tomcat and it's running. I also made my connection to the Oracle database. And now I want to hash my passwords making my app compare the hash code of the password that has been introduced through keyboard and the code of the password from the database(if the hashed codes are equal then the password is correct). I wrote some code in Java for hashing the password.

Could you help me with some ideas about what I have to do to have that hashed code in my database? How can I store that hashed passwords?

Comment: You could start with showing what you've got so far. Besides that a password is a string and a hash is one as well, so what's the problem with storing hashes instead of plain strings? One thing you should consider in your hashing (not directly linked to your question): add a static and dynamic salt to improve the security of your hashes.

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using J2EE authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your hashed password as a varchar column in your database.

Comment: @GhostCat: for generic question there's not much concrete answer. The app needs to store the password in the database (along the salt if Dora will care to implement..) Indeed the question is broad and we don't know what really bothers the author..

Comment: @slim Example of BCrypt hash: `$2a$04$ikuprq9tq7Kd2x3yHrdJ8uHd8Vr5EOfHKEa2Zazg/52iVn2fwd5M`. This is not an integer: it's a `$` followed by the version, `2a`, followed by a separator `$`, followed by the number of rounds `04` followed by a separator `$` followed by the hash. I would strongly consider using this string as is instead of trying to make a number of it.

Answer (score 1):

A typical hash algorithm returns an array of bytes. For example, Java's `MessageDigest`:

```
  byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest();
```

You can store this however you like. You will also need to store:

- The salt, if used (and you should)
- A "version number" to identify the hashing algorithm you used.

  - This is so that if one day you change algorithm, you know which one to
    use on old entries.

You could have three columns, `hash varbinary`, `salt varbinary`, `version integer`.

However it's quite common to encode all three into a single varchar:

- 2 chars for the version (a hex number)
- a fixed number of chars for the salt (hex or base64 - width depends on your algorithm and will vary with version)
- a fixed number of chars for the hash (hex or base64)

Encoding to printable ASCII characters makes it convenient for eyeballing the data, transmitting in the protocol of your choice, etc.